# Percentage. Value $x$ that removed $10\%$ result in $150.00$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question regarding the percentage.

How do I get the $x$ value that removed $10\%$ result in $150.00$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: $x$, less 10%, is $0.9x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $150 = 0.9x$. So to get $x$, we simply take $150 * \frac{10}{9}$.

Comment: Thank you for the catch. I've revised my answer and removed the extraneous information that was misleading (due to my poor reading abilities, apparently)!

Comment: The wording of the question is not entirely clear, so several readings are possible. But I believe that the one covered by your new answer is the intended one.

Answer (score 1):

We want some $x$ to have $10\%$ taken away to get $150$. This means that:
$$x-10\%\cdot x=150$$
$$x-0.1x=150$$
$$0.9x=150$$
I like working with fractions, so I will convert $0.9$ to $\frac{9}{10}$.
$$\frac{9}{10}x=150$$
$$x=\dfrac{150}{\left(\dfrac{9}{10}\right)}$$
$$x=150\cdot \dfrac{10}{9}$$
$$x=\dfrac{1500}{9}$$
$$x=\dfrac{500}{3}$$
If you want it in decimal form, then:
$$x=166.\overline 6$$